# Mixed named and unnamed function parameters

Tags: rest, web, go, jwt

I have this function for authenticating JWT tokens (not middleware), which says:

```
package main

import (
"net/http"
"log"
"fmt"
"github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func ValidateToken(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *jwt.Token {

//parse token
token, err := jwt.ParseFromRequest(r, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, err error) {
    return VerifyKey, nil
})

//validate token
if err != nil {

    switch err.(type) {

    //something went wrong during validation
    case *jwt.ValidationError:
        vErr := err.(*jwt.ValidationError)

        switch vErr.Errors {

        case jwt.ValidationErrorExpired:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "Token expired")
            return nil

        default:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "Error parsing token")
            log.Printf("Validation error: %v\n", err)
            return nil
        }


    //something else went wrong
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Error parsing token")
        log.Printf("Validation error: %v\n", err)
        return nil
    }

}

return token

}
```

Then, in my handlers, I call this function to get the token and check if it is valid using the Valid property in the JWT Token struct. However, when I run the web server, I get an error on line 13, saying:

```
Mixed named and unnamed function parameters
```

Line 13 is the jwt.ParseFromRequest() call. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? I am new to Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a function inline (of type `jwt.Keyfunc`), but not binding it to anything.  If `VerifyKey` is of type jwt.Keyfunc, then you can just change line 13 to

```
token, err := jwt.ParseFromRequest(r, VerifyKey)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
token, err := jwt.ParseFromRequest(r, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, err error)
```

Your function here returns two parameters, an interface, and and error.

You need to name BOTH like `( x interface{}, err error )`

or

You need to name NEITHER like `( interface{}, error )`

because,

What you have there right now is a parameter list of two error type parameters.

Like when you say:

```
var x, y, z int
```

you have a list of ints, you wrote that you have 2 comma-separated variables of type error named `interface{}` and `err`. The compiler knows `interface{}` is a stupid name for an error variable, and is pointing out that you need a variable for the first (what it presumes is really a) type, or you should ditch the word `err`.

Answer (score 0):

the same error can also occur if you forgot `,` in between the arguments list.

```
func someFunc(a string, b string c int) {}       // between string and c
```