# mixed named and unnamed parameters in golang

Tags: go

I am facing an issue with my code, and it is giving me an error:

> unnamed and mixed parameters

```
func(uc fyne.URIWriteCloser, error) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: In my case I missed a comma between the function arguments.

Answer (score 19):

It looks like you declared a function that has a named, and an unnamed parameter, which you cannot do.

There are two ways you can handle parameters in a func. You can either name all of the parameters, or provide no names to any of the parameters.

This is a valid func signature with both parameters named.

```golang
func(uc fyne.URIWriteCloser, err error) {
    // do something
}
```

And so is this, without naming the parameters.

```golang
func(fyne.URIWriteCloser, error) {
    // do something
}
```

If you were to name the first param, but leave the second param unnamed

```golang
func(uc fyne.URIWriteCloser, error) {
   // do something
}
```

Then you would see this error

```
Function has both named and unnamed parameters
```

So, the problem is that the second param simply declares the param type and not the name, while the first param is defining the type and naming the param.

Answer (score 3):

As specified in the [specs for Function Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types):

> Within a list of parameters or results, the names (IdentifierList) must either all be present or all be absent.
>
> - If present, each name stands for one item (parameter or result) of the specified type and all non-blank names in the signature must be unique.
> - If absent, each type stands for one item of that type.
>
> Parameter and result lists are always parenthesized except that if there is exactly one unnamed result it may be written as an unparenthesized type.

So either remove `uc`, or add `err error`.

Comment: See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36449724/6309